# How to know who installed IIS rewrite module on Window server

Tags: webserver, iis

I want to know how to know who installed the IIS rewrite module on the Windows server.

Is there any way to find it.

Comment: No, unless you installed some product that keeps a log of system changes (not standard part of IIS).

Comment: Windows Event Viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
Run eventvwr.msc → Windows Logs → Application
Search the application log for the 11707 event ID with MsiInstaller Event Source to find latest installed software.
Font: https://www.netwrix.com/how_to_detect_software_installations.html

If the user column is not listed, you can add it right clicking the columns. But if the installation happened a long time ago, your log might have been ricycled and won't be available.